# Efficiently using FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentpageradapter

I have an activity, inside which there is a `SearchView` and a `ViewPager`. If a user enters a string of length `n0` , where `n0 > 0`, in the `SearchView` and presses search, then the `ViewPager` will show `n0` fragments. If a user subsequently searches another string of length `n1`, then only those `n1` fragments will be shown in the view pager; I do not need the previous `n0` fragments anymore.

The way I am doing this is that my `ViewPager` has a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` that instantiates and supplies fragments in `getItem()`. When a user searches for a new string, I create a brand new `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and give it to my `ViewPager`. The problem is it does not look very efficient. When I look at the `FragmentManager`, I see its `mActive` still holds references to all the previous fragments.

How can I improve this?

Comment: Can you explain your use-case and what these fragments represent? Maybe you should use simple views instead if there is no complex logic.

Comment: It's a dictionary app. A user can enter a string of characters in the search view; and each fragment shows the definition for one character.

Comment: OK, then seems like you should be able to use just views in your adapter instead of fragments.